# Error installing GeoPandas?

Tags: installation, geopandas

Can someone help me with this error concerning installation of geopandas even after installing 'shapely'?

> Error:
>            cwd: C:\Users\JASHVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccci6ax2\fiona\
>       Complete output (1 lines):
>       A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a
>   GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th e logs for
>   full command output.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What were the detailed steps that you performed to try and install GeoPandas?

Comment: In general, I would also recommend to use `conda` instead of `pip` to install GeoPandas, see https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-with-anaconda-conda

Answer (score 13):

The problem is with `fiona` not with `shapely`, try to install it separately not as a dependence of `geopandas`

Download the right version for your Python version (the "cpXY" part of the filenames) from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs):

- Fiona: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)
- GDAL: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Then install it using `pip install path/to/gdal.whl` and `pip install path/to/fiona.whl`

And finally you can install `geopandas` using `pip install geopandas`

Comment: I tried and this occurs: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: @CésarArquero Try installing VCForPython27 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 if you are using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Use `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`.

Comment: This command also gives errors.. conda verification error:  The package for libwebp located at C:\xxx\xxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\libwebp-1.2.0-h2bbff1b_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/cwebp.exe'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found and multiple such errors for other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10 and I have same problem.

When I try first time install fiona with top-answer in topic (via .whl) I got error, but second time was successful (mb cython was need, I don't know). So my tries to install first time fiona below.

I wanted to install **geopandas**, but before it I had to install **Fiona**. And this was my solution:

1. Download binary gdal from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php). I choosed this: `release-1911-x64-gdal-2-4-4-mapserver-7-4-3`.

   1.1. You need to download 1 zip-file: `release-1911-x64-gdal-2-4-4-mapserver-7-4-3-libs.zip`

   1.2. Extract this to local path, e.g. `"C:\\Users\\Jack\\Gdal"`
2. Download Fiona from [master](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona). You can [download zip now](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)
3. Unpacking Fiona-master.zip, e.g. `"C:\\Users\\Jack\\Fiona-master"`
4. Open CMD, open dir "Fiona-master": `chdir "C:\\Users\\Jack\\Fiona-master"` and run this (with your paths):

   `python setup.py build_ext -I"<PATH_TO_GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR>" -lgdal_i -L"<PATH_TO_GDAL_LIB_DIR>" install --gdalversion 2.1`

   In my case:

   `python setup.py build_ext -I"C:\\Users\\Jack\\Gdal\\include" -lgdal_i -L"C:\\Users\\Vasilev_EN\\Downloads\\Gdal\\lib" install --gdalversion 2.1`
5. I didn't have cython and got error, so: `pip install cython`
6. Again try run long string from (4)
7. After success: `pip install geopandas` worked fine

Comment: That is very complicated and an old GDAL version. Didn't the top answer work for you?

Comment: top answer not working. I found link to solution here https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/449.

 solution shortly: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona#windows

Comment: It should work fine if you grab both Fiona and GDAL wheels from the site, that is super confusing though... You need to pick the right Python version ("cpXY").

Comment: in answers I didn't see requirement to install gdal via pip, so may be it was source of troubles

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue but have been able to get it properly installed using a combination of conda and pip installs.

1. Instal fiona using conda (`conda install fiona`)
2. Install geopandas using pip (`pip install geopandas`)